# Simple PHP Login - redirecting to a new webpage after successful login

Tags: php

I'm using the script below for logging in. I'm trying to redirect the users who were succesfully logged in to another webpage (visible only for logged in users), but it redirects everyone - regardless if the username and password are correct. What's should be changed in the code?

page with login form - `index.php` 
the page that I want to redirect to - `content.php`

**Table in my database**

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emailadress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
$name = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE name='$username' and pass='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{
echo "Login failed.";
}
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "Hello" . $username . "
";
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="content.php" name="login">

<?php
    if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
 ?>        
        <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="login">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sidenote: It seems like you are storing passwords in plain text, which is strongly advised you do not use, unless you're already using something to the effect of [`crypt()`](http://php.net/crypt) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function (*which I doubt*). Your code is also missing `session_start();` which is required when using sessions. *Plus*, in its present state, your code is open to [`SQL injection`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: You're using `and pass='$password'` yet your variable is called `$pass` where you have `$pass = $_POST['password'];` and `name='$username'` and you have `$name = $_POST['username'];` no match.

Comment: oh, my bad, sorry. no wonder it's not working :) thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You're welcome, I posted [`an answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22561923/) below for you to look at. Put a quick tick to close the question then. ;-)

Comment: I made another addition to my answer below. You have a trailing comma in `PRIMARY KEY (`\``id`\``),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pass='$password'` yet your variable is called `$pass`

where you have `$pass = $_POST['password'];` and `name='$username'`

and you have `$name = $_POST['username'];` there is no match.

Sidenote: It seems like you are storing passwords in plain text, which is strongly advised you do not use, unless you're already using something to the effect of [`crypt()`](http://php.net/crypt) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Your code is (*possibly*) missing `session_start();` which is required to be included inside **all** pages when using sessions. *Plus*, in its present state, your code is open to [`SQL injection`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo).

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future releases.

---

Another thing I noticed is that your SQL reads as:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emailadress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                    ^ // <- comma
)
```

Remove the last comma

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emailadress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

---

Here are a few redirection methods:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/content.php');
```

and if headers are giving you a hard time:

```
echo "You will be redirected in 5 seconds...";
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=http://www.yoursite.com/content.php>";
```

Another method is to add [`ob_start();`](http://php.net/ob_start) under your opening `<?php` tag which works at times.

Example:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
$name = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
...

header('Location: http://www.example.com/content.php');

...
```

Comment: if I have `session_start();` in the included `connection.php` file (see the edited question), should I also have it in the php code in `index.php` - as you wrote it in the last example (with `ob_start();`)
? :)

Comment: Just as long as your included file is inside all pages using sessions, yes. As for `ob_start();` that's just an option I mentioned in regards to, if you get an error message stating `headers already sent....` for the redirection. @dirigibleplum

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong with it

First. the action of your form is the protected page meaning that everyone will be redirected there in any case. You want to move your php code to login.php So that login.php looks like

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE name='$username' and pass='$pass'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 1){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: content.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "Wrong credentials";
        }
    }

    if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
 ?>
<form method="post" name="login">
        <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="login">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Note removing the action tag from the form - this way the browser will submit the page to itself, i.e. login.php

Your content.php should check that the user is logged in and get the username from the session

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        die("You are not logged in!");
    }
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "Hai " . $username;
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
?>
```

Remember to call session_start() in your scripts to tell PHP to create/invoke the existing session

Comment: Needless to say, never store password in the database unencrypted

Comment: Great, a nice thorough answer. Btw, if you want to make additions after you've written a post, just edit them in, rather than making addendums in comments. It keeps everything neat and in one place.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect do this:

```
    header('Location: content.php');
```

Comment: And `exit()` afterwards - PHP will quite happily carry on executing code after a `header`, even if that it not your intention `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is content.php. Anyone who submits the form goes to that page because of that. You'd have to make index.php or another separate page process the form in order for access to content.php to be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't call `session_start();` before using session variables.
2. the `form action="content.php"` is where your post is submitted not where it will be redirected.

Put `session_start();` before you use the session variables and put the redirect in the if block like this:

```
if($count == 1){
 session_start();
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 header("location: content.php");
}
```

and in your form action put action as index.php

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="login">
```

you can leave the form action empty if you are not using HTML5

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
header('Location: home.html'); or header('Location: home.php');
```